# Как отличить СИС от ПГС?

Tags: синтаксис

Например, у меня пусто было в кармане. Было или было пусто? И в данном случае слово "было" в значении обладания, бытия или часть СИС?

Answer (score 4):

У меня  пусто в кармане. У меня пусто было в кармане. У меня всегда будет пусто в кармане.

Это безличные предложения, наречие *пусто* обозначает признак, а грамматическое значение времени выражено связкой *быть*.

Также: Карманы пусты. Карманы были пусты. Это двусоставные предложения с именным сказуемым.

Глагол *быть* может быть **самостоятельным** и выражать факт существования предмета (но не признака), например: Была (стояла) зима (простое глагольное сказуемое). Зима была холодная (составное именное сказуемое, была — связка).

Answer (score 1):

Предложение типа **"у меня было"** невозможно, так не имеет законченного смысла. Здесь **"было"** употребляется в значении связки. Было пусто **(вопрос каково? - сказуемое).**